# How can I run MPI-Job in multiple nodes? (multinode MPI job execution)

Tags: mpi, scheduler, jobs, slurm

- Be able to execute a MPI job using multiple nodes to expedite the process
- This is the command I am currently using:
- `mpirun --hostfile myhost -np 2 --map-by slot  Job.x //only executes in the first node`
- `mpirun --hostfile myhost -np 4 --map-by slot  Job.x //explits the job in two different nodes`

myhost file contains the following:

- `node1 slots=2 max slots =20`
- `node2 slots=2 max slots =20`
- Assumptions: 
  I am able to run the jobs on the nodes but I am not able to run a single MPI job in multiple nodes. How do I make sure that a single MPI job is running parallel in two different nodes?

Comment: I don't think you tell what you *actually* want to do. **Why** do you specifically want to ensure that? Also what scheduler/batch system is involved (if any)? Have you asked your system administrator?

Comment: I suggest you to indicate which MPI implementation you use (mpich, openmpi, intel mpi, ibm mpi, ... ? ). Also, what do you mean that you are not able to run in multiple nodes? Does your application fail? and if so, how?

Comment: @Harald I am able to run the application on different nodes or instances of the same application on the same node. Now, I want to get only processes of the particular application running on different nodes. It is indeed possible because one MPI job usually releases many process once it is launched.

Comment: @Zulan I am using SLURM as the default scheduler. I want to ensure that happens because is relevant to the type of research I am doing.

Comment: This concepts are a lot clearer now. If anyone still has questions about it let me know.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have your processes in different nodes, you should try with this:

```
mpirun -n $SLURM_JOB_NUM_NODES -hosts $SLURM_JOB_NODELIST ./job.sh
```

The environmental variables are given when you have submitted the job, so assuming that the previous line is inside a bash script called *launch.sh*, you should submit:

```
sbatch -N4 ./launch.sh
```